# how to create a maven goal?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I use Maven 3.0.3. I need to run some static tests, in a Maven goal, without recompiling the project.

So, how can I create **my own Maven goal** and how can I **pass parameters** to this goal?

Does this mean that I should create my own Maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

`mvn test` will run tests after doing anything maven considers necessary, including compiling any out of date source files.

`mvn surefire:test` or `mvn failsafe:test` will run [unit](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html) or [integration](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) tests configured in the standard maven way without any recompilation. In general, `mvn plugin:goal` does just that one thing, `mvn goal` follows the [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

If your tests use neither the maven build lifecycle nor have a maven configuration, some other tool may be better at running them.